# Gradle: use wildcard in jar name in classpath

Tags: gradle, classpath, build-script

Gradle: use wildcard in jar name in classpath

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        flatDir {
            dirs "foo/lib"
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath name: 'bar-*-util'
    }
}
```

The bar version can be any version such as bar-1.0-util.jar, bar-2.0-util.jar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to add all the jars you have in a lib directory as follows:

```
dependencies {
    classpath fileTree(dir: 'foo/lib', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

or just specific jars as:

```
classpath fileTree(dir: 'foo/lib', include: ['bar-*-util.jar'])
```

And you don't need to specify a `flatDir` repository in that case.